# Permission denied trying to git clone over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, git

**Background**

I am trying to setup a git server on my vps with ssh access for me to clone, pull, push. Later I may add ssh clone access to anyone and a web repository browser. My vps runs Ubuntu 18.04 while my local machine runs XUbuntu 18.04. I understood that this is a simple matter of generating keys, appending them to the `authorized_keys` file, and voìla. Maybe not? What I have done so far is the following.

**Steps**

1. Make a ssh key pair on my local machine using`ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521`.
2. Made a regular user `ali` with sudo capability on the vps.
3. Made a git user `git` without sudo capability on the vps.
4. Appended the generated public key to both users' `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
5. Verified that the keys were appended using `cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
6. Tried to clone a test repo on my local machine using `git clone git@git.domain.io:test-repo.git`.
7. Added `ali` and `git` to group `gitusers`.
8. Gave `gitusers` group access to git directory using `chmod -R g+rws .`.
9. Verified that `ali` owns `/home/ali/.ssh/authorized_keys` using `ls -l`.
10. Verified that `git` owns `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` using `ls -l`.
11. Verified that `gitusers` can read,write `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` using `ls -l`.

**Error**

```
$ git clone git@git.domain.io:test-repo.git
git@git.domain.io: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**Question**

What step(s) did I miss?

I am able to ssh in using my local `ali` user. Do I need to juggle between a new `git` user to do any interaction with the git repos on the server?

Comment: Make sure that .ssh is chmod'ed 0700 and authorized_keys 0600.

Comment: I must not have done the before. I scraped the whole thing and re-did it, including using `chmod` as you said; and it worked. Should I edit my question or make and answer with my working (pseudo)script?

Comment: I don't know. All I can say is these permissions are a common oversight.